# VBScript filesystem issue

Tags: batch-file

I have the following vbscript

```
    Set colNamedArguments = WScript.Arguments.Named
    dim logFSO, logFile
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Set logFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>>>>    'Set logFile = logFSO.OpenTextFile("a.log", ForAppending, True)

    strFileURL = <passed from batch script>
         strHDLocation = <passed from batch script>
    WebUser = "user"
    WebPass = "pwd"


    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    'objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false, WebUser, WebPass
    objXMLHTTP.send()

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
      Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      objADOStream.Open
      objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

      objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
      objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

      'Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       ' If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
      'Set objFSO = Nothing

      objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
      objADOStream.Close
      Set objADOStream = Nothing
    End if

    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

I invoke the script in a loop from batch script, things are fine if the line starting with >>>> is commented, if it is uncommented, only one of the files is downloaded.
For example if I invoke it twice to download a.pdf ad b.pdf it downloads only one of them.
And if I comment out the line mentioned above, it downloads all files successfully. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you show us your .bat file - but the crystal ball tells me that you are invoking the VBscript twice and not waiting for the first to finish.

I'd try in your batch

```
start /wait vbscipt...
```

or

```
CALL vbscript...
```

As to the why - as a complete politician when it comes to VBScript, I'd suggest that you are opening the logfile for Appending and the second script runs while the first stil has that logfile open.